# Date to be displayed on load in input box from DatePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to display the previous month and year in input box just on load.

Now the date is being set and displayed once after focusing /Clicking on date picker.

Could anyone pls help me in displaying previous month and year (February 2016) just on load, which means before i click to select any date from datepicker

below is my code and Demo Link [JSFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/DBpJe/8107/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.monthYearPicker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'MM yy',
    yearRange: "-2:+0",
    defaultDate: '-1m'
  }).focus(function() {
    var thisCalendar = $(this);
    $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').detach();
    $('.ui-datepicker-close').click(function() {
      var Month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
      var iYear = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val(); 
      thisCalendar.datepicker('setDate', new Date(iYear, Month, 1));
      var iMonth = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").text();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<label for="startDate">Date :</label>
<input name="myDate" class="monthYearPicker" />
```

Comment: `displaying previous month and year` in the input?

Comment: Yes in the input field <input name="myDate" class="monthYearPicker" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Could anyone pls help me in displaying previous month and year (February 2016) just on load,*

You just need to use `setDate` like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.monthYearPicker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'MM yy',
    yearRange: "-2:+0",
    defaultDate: '-1m'
  }).focus(function() {
    var thisCalendar = $(this);
    $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').detach();
    $('.ui-datepicker-close').click(function() {
      var Month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
      var iYear = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
      thisCalendar.datepicker('setDate', new Date(iYear, Month, 1));
      var iMonth = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").text();
    });
  }).datepicker('setDate', "-1m y"); //<<-----set this here.
});
```

```css
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<label for="startDate">Date :</label>
<input name="myDate" class="monthYearPicker" />
```